# Record attribute not rendering as a string

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs

I am trying to access record attribute `odata.type` so I can modify my `EditForm` based on its value. I have created a constant that should do exactly that, but when I print it using `console.log` it displays like this for some reason:

```
ƒ HWType(_ref2) {
var record = _ref2.record;
 return react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("span", {
__source: {
  fileName: _jsxFileName,
  lineNumber: 31
},
```

My constant looks like this:

```
const HWType = ({ record }) => {
 return <span>{record ? record["odata.type"] : null}</span>;
}
```

Any suggestions how I can access `odata.type` attribute?

Thank you

Comment: can add sample record value? How you are using `HWType` ?

Comment: @Harish
I am using this constant so I can conditionally display fields if the condition si true. For example:

`{HWType === "HardwareDatabase.CPU" ? 
<ReferrenceSelectBox label="Socket" source="SocketTypeId" reference="CPUSocketType"></ReferrenceSelectBox>
 : null}`

Comment: `HWType` is your react component. you cant add condition like this. you have to treat your `const` as `const` not as `component`.

Comment: Oh ok, can I somehow modify that constant so it will return the attribute?

Comment: yes, you can modify it to `function`

Comment: @Harish could you specify that in an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display or hide input based on some value of `record` attribute, you can use `<FormDataConsumer>`. In your case it would look like this:

Firstly, you would have to add the input which you will be conditioning around:

```
<TextField source="odata.type" Name="HWType" disabled={true} />
```

Then:

```
<FormDataConsumer>
    {({ formData, ...rest }) => formData["odata.type"] === "HardwareDatabase.CPU" &&
      <ReferrenceSelectBox label="Socket" source="SocketTypeId" reference="CPUSocketType" {...rest}></ReferrenceSelectBox>
    }
</FormDataConsumer>
```

This way you should be able to display this specific input only if your `record` attribute is equal to `HardwareDatabase.CPU`

You can check out the `FormDataConsumer` here in the documentation:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#hiding-inputs-based-on-other-inputs

Answer (score 0):

`HWType` is your react component. you cant add condition like this. you have to treat your `const` as `const` not as `component`

```
const HWType = ({ record }) => {
 return <span>{record ? record["odata.type"] : null}</span>;
}
```

We can modify this to

```
const HWType = ({ record }) => {
 return record ? record["odata.type"] : null;
}
```

It can be used as

```
const obj = {record: '...'} // your actual object value
{HWType(obj) === "HardwareDatabase.CPU" ? <ReferrenceSelectBox label="Socket" source="SocketTypeId" reference="CPUSocketType"></ReferrenceSelectBox> : null}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately this solution does not seem to work for me, since `HWType(obj)` is undefined for some reason.

Comment: how are you using it in your code? can you create codepen for it?

Comment: I have defined both constants `HWType` and `obj` according to your code and then I have exported const `HardwareEdit` which contains inputs. There I have the condition.